# Scala polling loop without vars

Tags: scala, polling, idioms

What's the Scala best-practice for polling and API?

I'm trying to write a Scala method that polls an API, checking if it reached `"SUCCESS"`. While polling, it also might reach bad stated like `"FAILED"` or `"TIMEOUT`".

In Java, I'd write something like:

```java
public String pollEndpoint() {
  boolean isPolling = true;
  String result = "NA";
  while (isPolling) {
    Response response = getResponse("http://myAPI.com/ready?id=1234");
    if (response.status == "FAILED") { throw new FailedException(response.reason);}
    else ... //Some other bad conditions
    else if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
      isPolling = false;
      result = response.result; 
    }
    
    System.out.println("Current state is " + response.status); // When running, will be "RUNNING"
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

In Scala I can do:

```scala
def pollEndpoint():String = {
  var isPolling = true
  var result = "NA"
  while (isPolling) {
    val response = getResponse("http://myAPI.com/ready?id=1234")
    if (response.status == "FAILED") { throw new FailedException(response.reason)}
    else ... //Some other bad conditions
    else if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
      isPolling = false
      result = response.result 
    }
    println("Current state is " + response.status); // When running, will be "RUNNING"
    Thread.sleep(1000)  
  }
}
```

But this solution uses `var`s.

Is there any nice way of doing this, using only `val`s?

Comment: Any `while` loop can be rewritten as a simple tail-recursive function, where basically you receive the `isPolling` as an argument of such a function. - However, in this specific case it probably would be more idiomatic to make the API call **Async** and rather use some kind of **Stream** _(like `AkkaStreams` or `fs2`)_ for managing the polling rate and retry logic.

Answer (score 2):

As Luis mentioned in comment, you can just write a recursive for that:

```
def pollEndpoint():String = {
  val response = getResponse("http://myAPI.com/ready?id=1234")
  println("Current state is " + response.status); // When running, will be "RUNNING"
  if (response.status == "FAILED") { ??? }
  else if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
    response.result
  } else {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    pollEndpoint()
  }
}
```

The following will mock `getResponse`:

```
var i = 5
def getResponse(str: String): Response = {
  if (i < 0) {
    Response("SUCCESS", "Great success")
  } else {
    i = i - 1
    Response("Wait", "Not done yet.")
  }
}
```

And the call:

```
pollEndpoint()
```

Will produce:

```
Current state is Wait
Current state is Wait
Current state is Wait
Current state is Wait
Current state is Wait
Current state is Wait
Current state is SUCCESS
```

Having said all of that, it is way better instead of defining `getResponse` as it is, we might do:

```
def getResponse(str: String): Future[Response]
```

And then simply:

```
getResponse("http://myAPI.com/ready?id=1234").map { response =>
  // Handle response
}
```

Comment: The thing with the **Future** is that now the recursive function is a little bit more complex :) - And that is why it probably would be better to use something that makes handling that easier like a **Stream**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I am not sure this what the OP meant. It looks like a busy wait, with one result, because on success he breaks the loops and return the value. This why I don't think we need streams here. It feels more like a blocking java code that can be wrapped by a future.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what information determines the repetition (i.e. when to loop) and what information is returned to the outside world, but under the right circumstances you might `iterate()` instead of looping or recursing.

```
def pollEndpoint():String = {
  Iterator.iterate(getResponse("<yadda-yadda>")){ response =>
    response.status match {
      case "FAILED" => //log error, throw exception, etc.
      case stat     => //log whatever
                       Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    getResponse("<yadda-yadda>")
  }.dropWhile(_.status != "SUCCESS") //test for exit condition/s
  .next().result
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Iterator.iterate(). Why are you required to call getResponse inside the lambda?

Comment: In this case I chose to end each iteration with a call to `getResponse()` so that the result is passed to the next iteration for evaluation. That way the raw result is also tested for the exit condition. You can read more about `.iterate()` [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator$.html#iterate[T](start:T)(f:T=%3ET):Iterator[T]).